# Is it possible to set the seed of the ID in TFSO

Tags: azure-devops

I have migrated my local TFS project to TFSO. Unfortunately I could not use the OpsHub migration tool because the language of the local instance was German and therefore the work-itemscould not be transferred. I have introduced a lot of references to work-items in source-code. The problem is that now the `id`s starts with 1, resulting in references from code to work items that are not related.

Is it possible to set the ID in TFSO to a specific number in order to have newly created work-items to start with that number?

Comment: OpsHub tool can run on localized languages. What do you mean about the work items could not be transferred?

Comment: It told me that there are fields e.g. `Iterationspfad` that cannot be mapped. I have now imported the open work-items with excel, with the result that the id starts with 1. Fact that the project was rather new, there are not so many work-items that get references to the wrong commit.

Comment: Furthermore I have now changed the project type from `Scrum` to `Agile`, therefore a migration is not possible any more.

Comment: That's a known issue. Issue: If machine on which the Migration Utility is installed is on locale different then US, it might result in mapping related failures.
Workaround: Change the Windows locale, from Regional Settings to English (US), then restart the machine. Now re-run the migration, it should work fine. Refer to this link for details: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't any way to changeset or specify the Work Item ID. It is controlled by VSTS.

And the reference link between the changeset and workitem is stored in the workitem. So if the you haven't migrated the work items, don't worry about the incorrect reference for the code and work items.

Comment: that means: the work-item references that existed in TFS does not show up in TFSO when reaching the specific id that was reference by previous created commits?

Comment: @MichaelMairegger Yes.